# Замена картинки

Tags: jquery, изображения

Как лучше заменять одну картинку несколько раз. Подумав я пришел к таким вариантам.

- Менять scr (минус - если картинка большого размера, то загружается не сразу)
- Полностью менять html
- Грузить аяксом и потом заменять html

Хотелось бы услышать какой вариант лучше использовать и увидеть пример, или более менее годный мануал на русском.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать всё это можно гораздо проще:

```
var image=new Image();
image.onload=function(){
    //код замены
};
image.src='путь к изображению';
```

А "код замены" может быть двух вариантов:

а) Опять таки, замена `src`, которая должна пройти моментально, учитывая, что изображение уже было загружено:

```
original_image.src=image.src;
```

б) Замена непосредственно элементов, которая не должна заставлять браузер искать изображение в кэше:

```
var p=original_image.parentNode;
p.appendChild(image);
p.removeChild(original_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чем отличается в вашем понимании все эти 3 пункта? )

просто меняя html, у нас появится та же проблема что и меняя src. А что вы хотите грузить аяксом - я не понимаю.

Можно к примеру в JS добавить новый скрытый <img> с новой картинкой, и через какое то время (или по окончанию загрузки картинки) старую скрывать и удалять а новую показывать